# How to install a commercial version of "AmCharts" using npm

Tags: javascript, amcharts, npm-install

I am using AmCharts to build some charts for my app. I purchased the commercial version, but I’m unsure of how to install it using `npm install`.

On their docs they say: `npm install amcharts/amcharts3` 
However, this installs the free version.

The only way I can figure out how to install the commercial version is by downloading it from my Account section on their website. But I want to manage my install through npm.

Does anyone know if there is some sort of key I should have that I can just "activate" the free version with? Or another way to install the commercial version through `npm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to directly install the commercial version through npm. You'll need to contact AmCharts for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In this [site](https://www.amcharts.com/download/) informs to contact Support Center if you have **purchase a Commercial Version.**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did see that. But I was wondering if anyone else has found a way to install the commercial version through npm, not their download center.

Answer (score 1):

From what gather, the commercial version is mostly of use if you want to modify source. Given that you are asking about using via `npm` I'd hazard a guess that is not what you want to do..

**If you have purchased a license, and now simply want to remove the AmCharts branding:**

- Login to [AmCharts support centre](https://www.amcharts.com/sign-in)
- Go to [My Downloads](https://www.amcharts.com/support/my-downloads/)
- You should see instructions on how you can disable branding for your purchases using the standard `npm` packages

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase the license key and add it into your code?

```
amcore.addLicense("*license key*");
```